# How may I keep a horizontal-space for the following statement towards the right-hand side?

Tags: indentation

I would like to have 1.1., 1.2., and 1.3 shifted towards the right-hand side horizontally. I appreciate if someone could guide me to achieve this task. 
Thank you very much!

```
      \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
      \usepackage{blindtext}
      \usepackage{mathtools}
      \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

      \begin{document}
     {\normalsize Integral functions of one variable}\\
     {\footnotesize 1.1. Product of Binomials}\\
     {\footnotesize 1.2. Binomial theorem}\\
     {\footnotesize 1.3. Detached coefficients}\\
      \end{document}
```

Comment: `\hspace*{1cm}{\footnotesize 1.1....` But it all looks strange you should never need to number or layout a list by hand like this, it seems to be some form of table of contents?

Comment: I shall first be so grateful to you for providing me the answer.
That is what I wanted to know and the problem is solved.
Incidentally, this comes under my table of contents; as you have rightly guessed. I used \hspace{1cm} BUT not \hspace*{1cm}, so it did not work. Thanks to you it works perfectly now.

Comment: If it is a table of contents you should just let latex build it automatically with `\tableofcontents` doing it by hand is very error prone and you need to change it every time you edit the section headings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\hspace*{1cm}{\footnotesize 1.1.... #
```

But it all looks strange you should never need to number or layout a list by hand like this, it seems to be some form of table of contents

a table of contents should just be created with

```
\tableofcontents
```

Then LaTeX will automatically gather the section numbers and titles and build the list.

there are several packages that help with customising the format of the generated list if that is needed.

Comment: In all truthfulness, I did not know about such a command, because I recently started working with LaTex. Now I could go through a tutorial and start studying it. Thank you very much for the illustration, David!

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa That's OK everyone starts somewhere:-) I just didn't want to leave it with just the manual list version in my answer which is then there forever so added the pointer to \tableofcontents I started with latex in 1987 so a bit longer than you I guess:-)

Comment: lo and behold! You said that you started LaTex a 'bit longer'; well I was born in 1987. :D You have spent 27-years with LaTex, and you will be addressed as the 'LaTex knowledge factory'. :-)